# Access AzureFileStorage share from Worker Role?

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles, azure-files

I've created an Azure storage account and created a file share and put some files on a directory.  I want to access these files from a WorkerRole.  Is it possible to set this up so that it survives refreshes of the host cloud server and or worker role?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by going another way.

In the OnStart() of the WebJob copy the file from the AzureFileShare to a local directory and then access it as a local file.

```
   var tmpl = access.GetFile("reviewer-stats/templates/","revrStatsVer_2_3.xltx");
      if (!Directory.Exists(@"E:\reports\stat`enter code here`s\templates"))
          Directory.CreateDirectory(@"E:\reports\stats\templates");
      tmpl.DownloadToFile(@"E:\reports\stats\templates\Stats2.xltx",FileMode.Create);
```

You can find info on info on accessing Azure Files via C# [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files/)